# Counting array elements and sort descending by count

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Array:

```
5, 5, 5, 9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

Ideal Output:

```
2, 3, 5, 9, 4
```

PHP made this easy with `array_count_values()` and `arsort()`, but javascript is proving a little tougher. Any help?

---

Also, what about returning it containing the counts as well? For future needs

Comment: Check out the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array).  Then, of course, there is a .sort() method.

Comment: are you removing duplicates

Comment: Did you mean to say "descending by count"? The `2` is the most frequent occurrence...

Comment: @Floris Yes, Descending.

Comment: @aaronman Yes. But counting occurrences and sorting first.

Comment: @Xynariz Its not just removing duplicates and sorting. Read the post correctly

Comment: @GameDevGuru Sorry, the question wasn't clear to me.  I wasn't aware of the fact that you were looking for the order to be by counts (it's mentioned in your subject, but not your question).  Also, how do you want it sorted if there is a tie (in your example, there is only one 4 and only one 9)?

Comment: @Xynariz It doesn't matter.

Comment: In that case, @Paul's answer seems to cover it.

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_count_values/ phpjs can simulate the same function which in php. it may help you.

Comment: @bystander It puts the results in an object not an array.

Comment: @GameDevGuru ok..maybe It is not a good solution..

Comment: @GameDevGuru: Why would you need it in an array?

Comment: @Blender If i were to use array_count_values, i would need to sort descending through the count values. `.sort()` doesn't accept objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count unique entries, create an array of uniques, then sort based upon counts

```
function count(arr) { // count occurances
    var o = {}, i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (o[arr[i]]) ++o[arr[i]];
        else o[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
    return o;
}

function weight(arr_in) { // unique sorted by num occurances
    var o = count(arr_in),
        arr = [], i;
    for (i in o) arr.push(+i); // fast unique only
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return o[a] < o[b];
    });
    return arr;
}

weight([1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2]);
// one 1, two 3s, three 5s, four 2s
// [2, 5, 3, 1]
```

You example has both one `9` and one `4`, so if you want the order defined, more work would be necessary. Otherwise;

```
weight([5, 5, 5, 9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]);
// [2, 3, 5, 4, 9]
```

---

To produce an *Array* of *Objects*

```
function weight(arr_in) { // unique sorted by num occurances
    var o = count(arr_in),
        arr = [], i;
    for (i in o) arr.push({value: +i, weight: o[i]}); // fast unique only
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.weight < b.weight;
    });
    return arr;
}

var result = weight([5, 5, 5, 9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]);
/* [
    {"value": 2, "weight": 5},
    {"value": 3, "weight": 4},
    {"value": 5, "weight": 3},
    {"value": 4, "weight": 1},
    {"value": 9, "weight": 1}
] */
```

Now, to get the *value* at index `i`, you do `result[i].value`, and for it's weighting `result[i].weight`.

Comment: Could i also get output with count of each value? For future reference.

Comment: No i mean `2:5, 3:4, 5:3, 9:1, 4:1`

Comment: I've spent hours trying, but I can't seem to modify it properly.

Comment: You-re not being very clear - `2:5, 3:4, 5:3, 9:1, 4:1` does not make sense; do you mean the _Object_ `{2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}`? This is what is `return`ed by `count`. Alternatively, perhaps you want an _Array_ of _Objects_ like `[{value: 2, weight: 5}, {value: 3, weight: 4}/*, etc*/]` with which you would always thereafter need to specify whether you wanted the value or the weight. In my opinion using the _Object_ is easier as you can have it as a dictionary lookup if you ever wanted and does not require more code :)

Comment: Yea i would like it as a sorted array of objects so it's easier to iterate through. I come from PHP so i'm having a little trouble with this.

Comment: Count is working properly, it just wont sort by the count. I've tried everything!

Comment: The integers have various lengths. `eg: 333223, 2333,23444455` etc
I believe that's making a difference for sort

Comment: I fixed it.  `return b.weight - a.weight;`