# How to count how many duplicate strings in the array using JavaScript without sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen a lot of solutions for this but most of them implement the sorting function like arr.sort() which can be used with letters and integers.

Take a look at my array

```
arr = ["COINS", "SWORDS",  "COINS", "COINS", "STARS", "SWORDS", "KNIGHTS"];
```

What I want is to count all occurrences of the duplicate strings. For example, based on my array. I want something like this as a result

```
arr = ["COINS", "SWORDS",  "COINS", "COINS", "STARS", "SWORDS", "KNIGHTS"];
result => 5 (3 coins + 2 swords)
```

Anyone can tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: "*result => 5 (3 coins + 2 swords)*" doesn't make sense. Be accurate and specific

Answer (score 0):

The most logical way is to sort the array, then count the duplicates.

See here for an example: [Counting array elements and sort descending by count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007214/counting-array-elements-and-sort-descending-by-count)